# Wordpress looking in the wrong subdomain for wp-content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, subdomain

I have my wordpress installation at `/var/www/html/wordpress2` and there's a totally separate wordpress installation at `/var/www/html/html/wordpress`.

When running the worpdress2 installation, I get errors saying it can't find `/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/theme/....` How do I change it to look for these things in `wordpress2` and not `wordpress`?

Comment: Did you transfer wordpress to wordpress2? If so you need 2 separate databases, one for wordpress and the other for wordpress2. Then you need to check the wp_options table to have their correct subfolder in the site url and home url

Comment: Please make this an answer so I can name it as correct. Thanks =)

Comment: Made it an answer :) @bzupnick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you transfer wordpress to Wordpress 2? If so you need two separate databases, one for Wordpress and the other for Wordpress 2. Then you need to check the `wp_options` table to have their correct subfolder in the site URL and home URL.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps in order to transfer your WordPress site from one location to another.

1. Change the `option_value(your root url of current wordpress site)` corresponding to `id(value 1)` and `option_name(value site_url)`.
2. Access your `wp-admin(siteurl/wp-adimn)`. Go to general-setting panel and change Site Address (URL), same as WordPress Address (URL).

Hope this will work for you. Same process you can follow to move WordPress site from local to server or one server to another.